# SVGImage causing compiler errors in Unity SDK of Mapbox

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, svg, compiler-errors, mapbox

[Image of how SVGImage appears in IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTo7L.png)I have an issue with the Unity SDK where "SVGImage" causes 4 instances of the following compiler error:

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SVGImage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried changing the user directives to UnityEngine.UI; UnityEngine.Experimental, UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. This spreads across every C# file that references SVGImage.

public List hudImages;

```
public Color modeColor;

void Awake() {

    origImagecolors = new List<Color>();
    foreach (SVGImage image in hudImages) origImagecolors.Add(image.color);
}
```

Comment: Please avoid using links since they tend to die, and avoid using pictures of code since people can not grab the code and test it that way. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the Vector Graphics package from the package manager? I don't know the name of the top of my head but once you install the Vector Graphics Package (may be under preview packages so make sure its clicked) and then you alt click it in your Visual Studio you should see the prompt to import the reference.

Comment: I tried adding the Vector Graphics package and it created 13 more compiler errors due to it breaking associations with my other assets.

Comment: You need the package to use vectors, just fix your other compiler errors, they are just namespace errors right, be explicit with your assemblies and you will be fine